# System.Text.Json - Override global DefaultIgnoreCondition with attribute (JsonInclude)

Tags: .net-core-3.1, system.text.json

When you are serializing with this option:

```
DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault
```

Can you make exceptions for certain fields so that they still serialize (essentially overriding the options)?

Using [JsonInclude] attribute on the property (a bool type) does not work.

I tried it with a custom JsonConverter on the property but that too does not work (you never reach the Read/Write methods).

Answer (score 3):

Add the following attribute to the model property:

```
[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.Never)]
```